# Binding to ActualHeight does not work

Tags: wpf, binding, actualwidth, actualheight

I tried to create a custom control, having a semitransparent rounded background:

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock x:Name="StopText" Text="Some test text"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="SkyBlue"
               Width="{Binding Source=StopText, Path=ActualHeight}" 
               Height="20"  
               RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Opacity="0.2"/>
</Canvas>
```

The problem is that I can't, probably, bind to the `ActualHeight`/`ActualWidth` properties, cause they are not dependency ones.

What to do to mantain the rectangle and textbox of same size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct binding is to use `ElementName`, not `Source`, when binding to another element:

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock x:Name="StopText" Text="Some test text"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="SkyBlue"
               Width="{Binding ElementName=StopText, Path=ActualHeight}" 
               Height="20"  
               RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Opacity="0.2"/>
</Canvas>
```

Also, you do realize that you are binding the width of the `Rectangle` to the `Height` of the `TextBlock`, right?

If this is really the way you want to set up your control, you will want to bind the `Rectangle`'s Width to the `TextBlock`'s `ActualWidth`, and `Height` to `ActualHeight`.

**UPDATE**
Per the comments below, here is an implementation using a `Grid` with no binding:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock x:Name="StopText" Text="Some test text"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="SkyBlue"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
               RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Opacity="0.2"/>
</Grid>
```

`Grid` and `Canvas` [use different layout systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075911/grid-vs-canvas), and since you aren't using the functionality the `Canvas` provides, `Grid` is the better choice.

The big difference in the child elements is that the `Rectangle` now just uses Horizontal and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` across the entire `Grid`, instead of worrying about the sizes of anything.

Comment: Good observation about ElementName. What If I would like to bind it to the Canvas itself(the main element of the UserControl). What should I set?

Comment: I would simply use a Grid instead of a Canvas, and then you don't need any binding at all.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmm... With Canvas, I used `this.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty` to set the UserControl's location(inside the UserControl). How can I do now, with the Grid?

Comment: I believe even that there should be a way to stye the TextBox in order do not need "external" background rectangle...

Comment: #1.)  You can still set the Canvas.LeftProperty, even though it is a Grid.  #2.) Yes, you can certainly style a TextBlock (or TextBox, or any UIElement) by setting up a ControlTemplate using that UIElement's Template property.  That's a (the?) fundamental basis of WPF.

Comment: #1). I tested, and, unfortunately, this does not work, so I reset the Canvas as it was...

Comment: My mistake.  Still, you could essentially get the same effect by specifying the margin.  element.Margin = new Thickness(50d, 5d, 5d, 5d);